# Rails server not starting - rails 4.0.0.rc1

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am following the tutorial on http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ and now I am not able to start the server. In my gemfile I am using ruby 2.0.0 and rails 4.0.0.rc1 - then I tried changing back to ruby 1.9.3 and rails 3.2.13 - still not working

this is what terminal tells me:

```
/config/environments/development.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant FourTest (NameError)
    from /Users/markustorok/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/engine.rb:591:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
    from /Users/markustorok/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/engine.rb:590:in `each'
    from /Users/markustorok/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/engine.rb:590:in `block in <class:Engine>'
    from /Users/markustorok/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /Users/markustorok/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /Users/markustorok/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /Users/markustorok/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:150:in `block in tsort_each'
    from /Users/markustorok/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/markustorok/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:210:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /Users/markustorok/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:219:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /Users/markustorok/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:209:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /Users/markustorok/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
    from /Users/markustorok/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
    from /Users/markustorok/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:203:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /Users/markustorok/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:182:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/markustorok/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each'
    from /Users/markustorok/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/markustorok/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_each'
    from /Users/markustorok/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /Users/markustorok/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/application.rb:214:in `initialize!'
    from /Users/markustorok/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/markustorok/Dropbox/2Working/WebDesign/Ruby/rails_projects/speiseplan/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/markustorok/Dropbox/2Working/WebDesign/Ruby/rails_projects/speiseplan/config.ru:3:in `require'
    from /Users/markustorok/Dropbox/2Working/WebDesign/Ruby/rails_projects/speiseplan/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    from /Users/markustorok/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
    from /Users/markustorok/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
    from /Users/markustorok/Dropbox/2Working/WebDesign/Ruby/rails_projects/speiseplan/config.ru:in `new'
    from /Users/markustorok/Dropbox/2Working/WebDesign/Ruby/rails_projects/speiseplan/config.ru:in `<main>'
    from /Users/markustorok/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
    from /Users/markustorok/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
    from /Users/markustorok/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from /Users/markustorok/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:277:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
    from /Users/markustorok/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:199:in `app'
    from /Users/markustorok/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:48:in `app'
    from /Users/markustorok/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:314:in `wrapped_app'
    from /Users/markustorok/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:75:in `start'
    from /Users/markustorok/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/commands.rb:80:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/markustorok/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/commands.rb:75:in `tap'
    from /Users/markustorok/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/commands.rb:75:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any initialisers or lines in config files that make a call to a FourTest class? Because that class can't be found. Start by searching your code for FourTest then check that you've followed naming conventions on the file that contains the class and that it's in a folder that gets loaded by default (models folder) or that you are manually loading it before using it (lib folder, etc).